# How can the Move-Item command not find a file in the directory it is moving?

Tags: windows, powershell, file, server, directory

I am trying to move some Folders within a remote Directory.
I am Running a Powershell script on a Windows Server 2016.
All i am doing in my code is this.

```
Foreach ($directory in $directroys){
    try{
        Write-Output $directory
        Move-Item $directory $targetDirectory -Force -ErrorAction stop
    }catch{
        $errorMessage = $PSItem.ErrorDetails.Message
        Write-Output $PSItem.ErrorDetails.Message
  }
```

In most cases this works.
However sometimes I get a DirectoryNotFoundException while I am moving a folder. the Problem is not that it can't find the folder I am trying to move, but rather that it can't find a file in the folder that I am trying to move.
The error looks like this:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\bcciam\Desktop>> Write-Output $PSItem
Move-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At C:\Users\bcciam\Desktop\test2.ps1:224 char:9
+         Move-Item $directory $targetDirectory -Force -ErrorAction sto ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (ConfidentialFilename.pdf:FileInfo) [Move-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

This error occurs completely randomly.
How can the Move-Item command not find a file in the directory it is moving?
(This Error Probalby alwso occures when i want to delete the folder)

Comment: Are you sure `$directroys` is a valid variable name containing an array of directories? Seems misspelled to me..

Comment: If the file name is using a special character, or is over the 255 character limit (including the path) then you will get this error.

Comment: @Theo it is a array of path strings. and i misspelled it consistently.

Comment: since you failed to use the parameter names, the values were assigned to parameters based on position. the 1st is `-Path` [position 0] ... and `-Path` does not tolerate some special characters [square brackets, for instance]. [*grin*] try  specifying the parameter names and using `-LiteralPath` instead of the default `-Path`.

Comment: @Scepticalist you are probably right. The file is tecnicaly to long for its path. and i think tats why it cant find the file.